# Probability x>=yz if the three are randomly distributed in the interval [0,1]

Tags: probability, gre-exam

I'm practicing for the GRE subject test and this was one of the questions I missed. I know that the answer is $^{3}/_{4}$, but I'm not quite sure why. One thing I thought of is that the average values for each y and z are $^{1}/_{2}$ so that their product is $^{1}/_{4}$, and of course $^{3}/_{4}$ of the interval consists of numbers greater than $^{1}/_{4}$. However, I have absolutely no rigorous justification. What would the rigorous argument be?

On a side note, I have solutions for the two most recent subject tests, but not the test administered in 1993. Can anyone point me toward one? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: compute
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_{yz}^11dxdydz.
$$

Comment: It might be noted that this can be derived from the integral of the indicator function which is $1$ if $x\geq yz$ and $0$ otherwise, over the entire domain $[0,1]^3$...

Comment: Thank you both! That last comment was especially helpful. I see now - essentially, you're first computing the integral of the PDF for x being greater than the product, and then the y and z integrals are just there to "add up" (in the infinitesimal limit) over each possible value of y and z. Is that it?

Comment: @BGreen Formally, the probability you seek is $\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1I(x\geq yz)f(x,y,z)dxdydz$ where $f(x,y,z)$ is the pdf of the joint variable $(X,Y,Z)$ and $I(\cdot)$ is the indicator function. Then you use independence to factor out $f(x,y,z)$ as a product of the three marginals.